# Angular: Remove error message at the beginning, show it until the user search stuff (?)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-filters

I have I little issue which I got done in a web app, now, I have the same issue on a mobile app but I can't fix it the same way I did it with web.

[Look at this video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpMT4rQsPN4&feature=youtu.be)

as you can see the user logs in and at the very beginning the 1st thing you will see is a banner **"Did not match any search criteria"**, and that's what I want to avoid, that banner has to be displayed only when the filter returns nothing and not at the beginning when the user hasn't type anything in the search box.

Now, take a look at my code here:

```
<ion-content>
 <!--search input-->
 <label class="item">
   <input type="search" ng-model="query">
 </label>
 <!--this is the banner-->
 <div ng-show="!sportsFilter.length">
  <i class="icon"> Did not match any search criteria</i>
 </div>
 <!--here is what I am filtering-->
 <div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query)"
      ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: can u make a jsfiddle?

Comment: if I do it will work correctly because the data will be load instantly. The reason why that banner is showing first, is because that data.length is zero while requesting the info from the data base, once the info is loaded, the banner disappears because the length of that array will be with some items loaded. Hope you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically on load sportsFilter should be sportsFilter = undefined

and

```
<div ng-show="!!sportsFilter && sportsFilter.length == 0">
   <i class="icon"> Did not match any search criteria</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div  ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query)">
<div ng-show="!sportsFilter.length">
  <i class="icon"> Did not match any search criteria</i>
 </div>
 <!--here is what I am filtering-->
 <div ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually this is the proper way to do it.

```
<div ng-show="!sportsFilter.length && query.length">
 <i class="icon"> Did not match any search criteria</i>
</div>
```